# php array ( if keys repeats 2 times then sum the values

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress insert to database allways inserts new rows ... i try to use the replace but still no joy, im using:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->replace(bruno_wallet, array( 'nome' => $nome[0],
'valorhora' => $valor_horas ,
'data' => $data ,
'evento' => $evento ,
'horarios' => $horarios,
'obs' => $obs,
'foto' => $ii,
'totalparcial' => $total_parcial,
'id_do_mes' => $id_postt,
'horas' => $numeros_horas ));
```

to insert on wordpress to database, but i want to only insert if it dosent exists...but now it allways adds new entrys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of Update Function in WordPress. Did you check the format of the data inserted? If you omit format parameter everything will be considered string that may be the reason WP was not able to detect the row already exists. Try with format of the input `%s %d %f` . The below link might help you [Update_rows Guide](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)